# A guide to self moderation -- help moderate Islam.SE

Tags: discussion, moderation

One of the goals of this site (and if I am not mistaken, of all the sites on Stack Exchange) is to gain enough high reputation users for the site to moderate itself.  Users of a community [help moderate the site based on their reputation level and privileges](https://islam.stackexchange.com/privileges/). For example when a user has reached 2000 reputation, that user will be able to access the [Moderator Tools](https://islam.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools), enabling that users to help diamond moderators in two *Major* ways:

1. Post deletion
2. Flag Handling

Currently there are 12 users with, and over 2000 reputation.  When a user has 4000 reputation, [they would be able to do a number of things](https://islam.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user), including deleting posts that are down-voted and un-deleting posts.  There are 3 non-diamond moderator users that have 4000 reputation.

Diamond Moderators are to intervene in exceptional cases, but they are expected to not intervene all the time and to help guide the community. The community ***must*** help moderate itself.  With the number of users we have that are not diamond moderators and have enough reputation, we can start trying to moderating this site.  **Every single user** helps to build this community and to protect this site through moderation.

Users can help moderate our site, and keep it in order by doing some of the following:

1. **Up-vote** good posts and **down-vote** the bad
2. **Edit** posts to make them stronger, either by improving the language, changing the tags, or by adding links/images/background info.
3. **Comment** on posts (especially new users' posts) and help explain how the user can improve their question/answer (if it can be) so that the owner of the post can change/fix any problems.
4. **Vote to close** questions that need closing -- anything off-topic, that would solicit debate or discussion, or which is relevant only to one person's situation should be closed.
5. **Flag** posts (and comments) that need flagging -- this will help moderators see any problem activities. This will also prevent arguments from taking over the front page of the site.
6. **Vote to delete** posts that need deleting -- spam, self-promotion, and other types of posts that do not answer a question or that are offensive/hateful.

We **need *your* help** to keep order in this community by helping to moderate it.

Comment: This is truly an excellent post.